# doesn't add img from array to div background

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a background image to a div from an array. It works when I just set the background like this:

```
div.style.background = "url(path/to/img.jpg) no-repeat"
```

But if I take it from an array such as this:

```
const array=[
    '"url(path/to/img.jpg) no repeat"', 
    '"url(path/to/img2.jpg) no repeat"', 
    '"url(path/to/img3.jpg) no repeat"'
];
div.style.background = array[1];
```

it does not work.

```
const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
const photos = ['"url(img/DSC_0387.JPG) no-repeat"', '"url(img/DSC_0389.JPG) no-repeat"', '"url(img/DSC_0392.JPG) no-repeat"', '"url(img/DSC_0393.JPG) no-repeat"', '"url(img/DSC_0399.JPG) no-repeat"'];

function add() {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.background = photos[2];
  div.style.borderRadius = "10px";
  div.style.height = "350px";
  div.style.backgroundSize = "contain";
  grid.appendChild(div);
};
add();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In photos Array change the values of the array as below. Remove the single quotes for the values of the array.

```
const photos = [
  "url(img/DSC_0387.JPG) no-repeat",
  "url(img/DSC_0389.JPG) no-repeat",
  "url(img/DSC_0392.JPG) no-repeat",
  "url(img/DSC_0393.JPG) no-repeat",
  "url(img/DSC_0399.JPG) no-repeat"
];
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the double set of quotes in the `photos` array.

i.e. `'"url(img/DSC_0387.JPG) no-repeat"'` becomes `'url(img/DSC_0387.JPG) no-repeat'`

```js
const grid = document.getElementById("grid");
const photos = ['url(img/DSC_0387.JPG) no-repeat', 'url(img/DSC_0389.JPG) no-repeat','url(img/DSC_0392.JPG) no-repeat','url(img/DSC_0393.JPG) no-repeat','url(img/DSC_0399.JPG) no-repeat'];

function add(){
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    console.log(photos[2]);
    div.style.background = photos[2];
    div.style.borderRadius = "10px";
    div.style.height = "350px";
    div.style.backgroundSize = "contain";

    grid.appendChild(div);
};
add();
```

```html
<div id="grid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to StackOverflow.

Your photos array has double-quotes wrapping the value, you should remove it.

The quotes will be handled automatically, you just need to pass a normal string to `div.style.background` with the desired value. Currently you're passing a string that starts with `"`, thus being not a valid value for this attribute, resulting in this not being rendered on DOM.